# Cocoapod public distribution technique

Tags: ios, swift, git, cocoapods, podspec

I am very new in iOS development and I have some queries that I hope to get some assistance.

I have created an iOS framework and I have uploaded the codebase to a private git repository and released a tag.
Now I created another private git repository where I'm keeping its corresponding podspec. The source defined in this podspec is the link for the iOS framework git repository.

Integrators don't have access and are not supposed to interact with the cocoapod directly. They are only supposed to interact with the SDK. The SDK does have access to the cocoapod and uses a username/password to access the private cocoapod.
I want this iOS framework to be distributed publicly to integrators as an SDK, without making any of my git repositories (and the main codebase) as public. Kind of the following structure:
[Integrators] -> [SDK] -> [cocoapod]

How can I achieve that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: basically you are asking how to make cocoapod to be publicly available without making it publicly available - that's an oxymoron. You need to make podspec and cocoapod public for them to be public. You can of course do it not in original repos, but by copying both to some other public repos

Comment: @KirilS. My interpretation of what he is trying to say is different. He said he has an iOS framework. I believe what he is trying to say is, the iOS framework references a private cocoapod. Let's say that cocoapod is another internal framework, like a common framework for example. And then he wants to distribute the framework to Integrators and wants to know if that setup is possible.

All in all, he should use different language. Let's call the distributed code a SDK, and the SDK is referencing a framework which was turned into a cocoapod.

[Integrators] -> [SDK] -> [cocoapod]

Comment: @KirilS. Sorry for the incorrect structuring of my question. The scenario that portfoliobuilder mentioned is correct. I've now edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

You can distribute a compiled framework though Cocoapods. This will allow you to keep your source code from being leaked to the Integrator. And also prevent your framework from being compiled on every clean build on the Integrator app.

By distributing compiled code we:
--Keep our code secret
--Save time in the app compilation process

Run the following commands:

```
cd ~
curl -o MyFramework.zip -L 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/5vykpag4xb5vh51/MyFramework.zip -s
unzip -q MyFramework.zip
```

The command above fetches the framework project. The simplest form of compiling a Swift framework is through the Xcode user interface.

```
open -a Xcode ~/MyFramework/MyFramework.xcodeproj
```

Select Generic iOS Device from device list. Lastly build the framework by selecting from menu Product > Build.

After the build process finishes you’ll find the built framework in the `Products` folder.

To learn more about this process, you can follow this tutorial online.

Ref-
https://medium.com/onfido-tech/distributing-compiled-swift-frameworks-via-cocoapods-8cb67a584d57